# Windows Phone Pivot Page Not Responsive

Tags: windows-phone

quick question.
How do I make the pivot page in my app responsive? I create a simple pivot page with 3 pivot item (no content yet), and I try to swipe to right/left really fast (ex: 1st pivot to 3rd pivot) but the response's slow.

I view another app created by someone else, example DualShot (about page) when I swipe fast to  another pivot page, it's really fast! how do I achieve this?

Note: I have no Idea what to search in Google, everything redirect me to responsive web page.

Comment: Did you try to create a new project with one Page with a Pivot on it, and deploy it to device without a debugger. Is it still slow?

Comment: @AntonSizikov ok now I know the problem, after I create two project (1st target = WP7.1, 2nd target = WP8). The application that target WP7.1 is not responsive (WP8 is responsive). I want to create an app that available both in WP7.1 and WP8? is it possible if I create project that target WP8?

Comment: No, WP7 app can be launched on WP8 device, but WP8 app can't run on WP7 device.